# Why @Autowired and @Inject on field is not recomended but @Resoruce is fine in Spring/IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

I have noticed that Intellij warns me about using field injections with `@Autowired` and `@Inject` annotations. However, using `@Resource` is on field is fine. What is the reasoning behind this?

Please be noticed that I am not asking about why field injection is discouraged. I want to know why injection via `@Resource` is "better/safer" - at least according to some lint rules

Comment: Probably because unlike Inject and Autowired, you can't apply the Resource annotation to a constructor.

Comment: Aaaah so its not "better" but its the only option for that annotation (in this limited scope).